# What is the difference node *node1 vs node* node1?

Tags: c, pointers, syntax

I have 1 node:

```
struct node
    {
        int key;
        struct node *left, *right;
    };
```

What is the difference between

```
node  *node1
```

vs

```
node*  node1
```

?

Comment: The way C declaration syntax works, the "pointer-ness" of an object is specified as part of the *declarator*, not the type specifier.  Given the declaration `int *p`, the `int`-ness of `p` is specified by the type specifier `int`, while the pointer-ness of `p` is specified by the *declarator* `*p`.  The declaration is *parsed* as `int (*p);`, meaning a declaration like `int* p, q;` would be parsed as `int (*p), q;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a `typedef`, both the declarations are illegal.

With a `typedef` like

```
 typedef struct node node;
```

in place, there's no difference. Both the statements declare a variable `node1` of type pointer to `node`. (*Note: You'll still be needing the terminating `;`, though*).

It's a matter of choice, but some (including me) prefer to attach the pointer notation to the variable, to avoid misunderstanding, in case of multiple variable declaration, like

```
 node *p, q;
```

where, `p` is pointer type, but `q` is not.

Writing it like

```
 node* p, q;
```

*may* create the illusion that `p` and `q` both are of pointer type, where, in essence, they are **not**.