# Pointer assignment error C

Tags: c, pointers, types

I have a struct defined as:

```
typedef struct _InstNode{
    
    InstInfo* instinfo;
    struct _InstNode *dep1;
    struct _InstNode *dep2;
    bool is_exit;
    bool is_entry;
    unsigned inst_latency;
    unsigned  depth_latency;
} InstNode;
```

and this is instnode_array :

```
InstNode *instnode_array;
    instnode_array = (InstNode*)malloc(sizeof(InstNode)*numOfInsts);
```

Now I'm trying to do the following:-

```
instnode_array[i].dep1 = instnode_array[j];
```

I'm getting this error:

> incompatible types when assigning to type `'struct _InstNode *'` from type `'InstNode` {aka `struct _InstNode`}'
>
> ```
>   instnode_array[i].dep1 = instnode_array[j];
> ```

Comment: `instnode_array` is no array....

Comment: @SouravGhosh it's an array of pointers.. how come not?

Comment: Array of pointers? How come?

Comment: Names starting with underscore are reserved for the implementation in all file-scope namespaces! IOW: you may not use them!

Comment: 1) A pointer is not an array! 2) A `struct` is not a pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR** <del>Note</del> Honor the data types.

`instnode_array[j]` gives you a `struct _InstNode` whereas, `dep1` is of type `struct _InstNode *`.

You may want to write

```
instnode_array[i].dep1 = &(instnode_array[j]);
```

if that make sense to you.

Comment: another related question If I may:
When I write the field dep1 this way:  `struct _InstNode *dep1;`
It gives me error but, when I write it this way : `struct _InstNode* dep1;` It builds with no errors.. any explanation?

Comment: @Ameerkhan I don't see any reason. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44055041/2173917)

Comment: I checked it 30 minutes ago and didn't find any reason also. I think it is just an eclipse thing.

Comment: @Ameerkhan No error should happen. If you told us _what_ error you get, we could assess it further. When telling people that something gives you an error, always tell them what it is.